# Loading an image in HTML Canvas after maze generation is complete

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating a maze application with Canvas and having a token traverse the maze from start to finish.

I completed the maze generation and am trying to generate a token at grid (0,0). I've created a button to select a token and throwing a debugger at the end does show that the icon is created in the right position, but it is not persisting after I continue. I've tried adding the image.onload to the drawImage function, but it is still not working.

This was what I originally had that rendered the image on Canvas while in debugger

```
function selectIcon(){
    let body = document.querySelector("body")
    let image = document.createElement("img")
    image.src = "image.jpg"
    body.prepend(image)
    // debugger
}

function clickHandler(){
    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        button = e.target
        console.log(button)
        if(button.matches(".choose-token")){
            renderIconToCanvas()
        }
    })
}

function renderIconToCanvas(){
    const myCanvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
    myCanvas.setAttribute("id", "maze-canvas")

    const image = new Image;
    image.src = "maze/image.jpg"
    
    let ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

All of the solutions that I've read say to add  image.onload to the drawImage, but when I put it in, my image no longer renders in debugger.

```
function renderIconToCanvas(){
    const myCanvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
    myCanvas.setAttribute("id", "maze-canvas")

    const image = new Image;
    image.src = "maze/image.jpg"
    
    image.onload = function (){
        let ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Is there something else that I might be missing? Another way that I tried:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const image = new Image(20,20);
    image.src = "./image.jpg"
    
    function draw(ctx, image){
        if (!image.complete){
            setTimeout(function(){
                draw(ctx, image);
            }, 50);
            return
        }
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }
    draw(ctx, image)
```

Comment: Assign your `load` Event before the `.src` , otherwise it might never fire.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help with the rendering. Any other ideas?

Comment: Last attempt is futile. Your canvas needs a `width` and `height`.

Comment: I have two additional files that generate the maze and assign a width and height. Would I need to set the width/height again here?
https://github.com/vincentyang01/maze-client/blob/master/src/sketch.js
https://github.com/vincentyang01/maze-client/blob/master/src/cell.js

Comment: Add an `img.onerror = console.error` handler and check your console. If it fires then go to the Network panel of your dev tools and find out why it failed to load.

Comment: Nothing in the network tab is failing

Comment: @Vincent but still the error message fired? That would mean your image file is broken.

Comment: @Vincent - I'm afraid without additional information we won't get any further. Can you provide a more complete code snippet that clearly shows your issue? At least the above solution including the onload event should work.